# Scala - flattening a tree structure

Tags: scala, flatmap

I have a tree structure I'm receiving from a Java library.  I am trying to flatten it since I'm interested only in the "key" values of the tree. The tree is made up of zero or more of the following classes:

```
class R(val key: String, val nodes: java.util.List[R]) {}
```

with an empty *nodes* list representing the end of a branch. A sample can be build via this code:

```
val sample =  List[R](
  new R("1",  List[R](
    new R("2",  List[R]().asJava),
    new R("3",  List[R](new R("4",  List[R]().asJava))
      .asJava)).asJava)).asJava
```

I am having trouble writing both a correct method, and an efficient method. This is what I have so far:

```
def flattenTree(tree: List[R]): List[String] = {
  tree.foldLeft(List[String]())((acc, x) => 
             x.key :: flattenTree(x.nodes.asScala.toList))
}
```

However when I run this code, as inefficient as it may be, I still get it incorrect. My result ends up being:

```
>>> flattenTree(sample.asScala.toList)
res0: List[String] = List(1, 3, 4)
```

which means for some reason I lost the node with key "2".

Can someone recommend a correct and more efficient way of flattening this tree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a function to flatten an `R` object with `flatMap`:

```
// required to be able to use flatMap on java.util.List
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

def flatten(r: R): Seq[String] = {
  r.key +: r.nodes.flatMap(flatten)
}
```

And a function to flatten a sequence of those:

```
def flattenSeq(l: Seq[R]): Seq[String] = l flatMap flatten
```

`r.nodes.flatMap(flatten)` is a `Buffer`, so prepending to it is not efficient. It becomes quadratic complexity. So, if the order is not important is more efficient to append: `def flatten(r: R): Seq[String] = r.nodes.flatMap(flatten) :+ r.key`

Comment: I am not sure, maybe I'm something, but the children are java.util.List which do not support flatMap. I'd have to do a conversion asJava again? So flatten's body would become "r.key +: r.nodes.asScala.toSeq.flatMap(flatten3)" ?

Comment: @WillIAm Oh, sorry, I forgot to include the import to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! This JavaConversions._ vs JavaConverters._ is very confusing. :) I had the latter.

Answer (score 4):

You are failing to add in the accumulated keys on each successive call. Try the following:

```
def flattenTree(tree: List[R]): List[String] = {
  tree.foldLeft(List[String]())((acc, x) =>
             x.key :: flattenTree(x.nodes.asScala.toList) ++ acc)
}
```

which generates the result: `List(1, 3, 4, 2)`,

or, if proper ordering is important:

```
def flattenTree(tree: List[R]): List[String] = {
  tree.foldLeft(List[String]())((acc, x) =>
             acc ++ (x.key :: flattenTree(x.nodes.asScala.toList)))
}
```

which generates the result: `List(1, 2, 3, 4)`

Comment: Thanks, that gets me over the hump. I can continue and hopefully someone later will come up with a suggestion for better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Convert each `R` to a [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) [`Tree`](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.Tree), and call `flatten` to do a pre-order traversal.

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scalaz._

def rTree(r: R): Tree[String] =
  Tree.node(r.key, r.nodes.toStream.map(rTree))

sample.flatMap(r => rTree(r).flatten): Seq[String]
// List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Edit: Unfortunately, due to [a bug in scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/issues/1001) as of version 7.1.1, this causes a stack overflow for wide trees.

Comment: Hmm, I tried your suggestion and increased my nodes to 10000 items, but I ended up with a stack overflow (somewhere between 1000 and 10000). The only change from the code above was to change List[String] to Seq[String] to make the compiler happy. I was going to go with this approach since it seemed a bit faster than the one suggested above by Kolmar.  http://pastebin.com/BbCEm4H4

Comment: The stack overflow seems to be a bug in scalaz :(

Answer (score 1):

What about using `Stream`s like `scalaz` does:

```
def flatten(rootElem: R): Stream[String] = {
  def flatten0(elem: R, xs: Stream[String]): Stream[String] =
    Stream.cons(elem.key, elem.nodes.foldLeft(xs)((acc, x) => flatten0(x, acc)))

  flatten0(rootElem, Stream.empty)
}
```